# Successfully changed IP address but 'ip addr' and 'ifconfig' don't show it

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, network-interface, ifconfig, ip-address

I've searched all over the google for an answer.

I've statically changed my ip address but nothing detects it. I can successfully ping and SSH to any host on my subnet but `ip addr` and `ifconfig` still show my old ip address that I obtained from DHCP.

`/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto enp63s0
iface enp63s0 inet static
address 172.16.24.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 172.16.24.1
```

I am not going to list my old ip for security's sake but it was xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/22 and that is the same as what ifconfig displays.

Is this due to an incorrect path of some sort?

Thanks much,

Comment: BTW If it's a `172.16.0.0/12` address it's a private address meaning it's about as secretive/meaningful as a `10.0.0.0/8` address.

Comment: What, exactly, did you do to change your IP address? What makes you believe that you "successfully changed" your address? Was the old address in a different subnet range? Were you able to ping and connect to other hosts on your subnet before you changed your address? When you connect (ssh) to another host, and then run `netstat`, can you figure out what address you're connecting from?  Please do not reply in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

man 5 interfaces, 1st line

```
ifdown enp63s0
ifup enp63s0
```